# Could not locate the bindings file when using docker compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have a project I'm working on utilizing a Node Docker image I created plus a Postgres image I pull from Docker Hub. Both are put together using the docker compose file below. However when running `docker-compose up` I get the error below. Can someone help point me in the right direction as to what is causing this?

**Dockerfile**

```
# Use latest LTS version of Node version 14 available from Docker Hub
FROM node:14

# Create app directory where we will hold the application
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn install

# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

CMD [ "node", "index" ]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    r2d8-bot:
        image: r2d8-bot
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        networks:
            - r2d8
        volumes:
            - ./:/usr/src/app
    postgres:
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        image: postgres:alpine
        networks:
            - r2d8
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - postgres-data:/data/db
networks:
    r2d8:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    postgres-data:
        driver: local
```

**Error**

```
yarn run v1.22.4
$ docker-compose up
Pulling postgres (postgres:alpine)...
alpine: Pulling from library/postgres
540db60ca938: Pull complete
a3cb73039552: Pull complete
39855706e49a: Pull complete
19d88c3ceadb: Pull complete
9ef572e3c9bb: Pull complete
261ea2d28080: Pull complete
1716633ec467: Pull complete
051e02f33f5f: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:7e2805cfa714bca16c4211b4f102c34934626cd557c73abfc70c1667deba3138
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:alpine
Recreating r2d8_postgres_1 ... done
Starting r2d8_r2d8-bot_1   ... done
Attaching to r2d8_r2d8-bot_1, r2d8_postgres_1
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  | 2021-05-29 17:33:01.071 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.2.1_pre1) 10.2.1 20201203, 64-bit
postgres_1  | 2021-05-29 17:33:01.071 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2021-05-29 17:33:01.071 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2021-05-29 17:33:01.079 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1  | 2021-05-29 17:33:01.089 UTC [22] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-05-29 17:32:44 UTC
postgres_1  | 2021-05-29 17:33:01.094 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
r2d8-bot_1  | /usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/index.js:43
r2d8-bot_1  |           throw err
r2d8-bot_1  |           ^
r2d8-bot_1  |
r2d8-bot_1  | Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
r2d8-bot_1  |  → /usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/build/addon.node
r2d8-bot_1  |  → /usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/build/Debug/addon.node
r2d8-bot_1  |  → /usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/build/Release/addon.node
r2d8-bot_1  |  → /usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/out/Debug/addon.node
r2d8-bot_1  |  → /usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/Debug/addon.node
r2d8-bot_1  |  → /usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/out/Release/addon.node
r2d8-bot_1  |  → /usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/Release/addon.node
r2d8-bot_1  |  → /usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/build/default/addon.node
r2d8-bot_1  |  → /usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/compiled/14.17.0/linux/x64/addon.node
r2d8-bot_1  |  → /usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/addon-build/release/install-root/addon.node
r2d8-bot_1  |  → /usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/addon-build/debug/install-root/addon.node
r2d8-bot_1  |  → /usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/addon-build/default/install-root/addon.node
r2d8-bot_1  |  → /usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-x64/addon.node
r2d8-bot_1  |     at bindings (/usr/src/app/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:126:9)
r2d8-bot_1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/index.js:1:46)
r2d8-bot_1  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
r2d8-bot_1  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
r2d8-bot_1  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
r2d8-bot_1  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
r2d8-bot_1  |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
r2d8-bot_1  |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
r2d8-bot_1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg-native/index.js:1:13)
r2d8-bot_1  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30) {
r2d8-bot_1  |   tries: [
r2d8-bot_1  |     '/usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/build/addon.node',
r2d8-bot_1  |     '/usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/build/Debug/addon.node',
r2d8-bot_1  |     '/usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/build/Release/addon.node',
r2d8-bot_1  |     '/usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/out/Debug/addon.node',
r2d8-bot_1  |     '/usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/Debug/addon.node',
r2d8-bot_1  |     '/usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/out/Release/addon.node',
r2d8-bot_1  |     '/usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/Release/addon.node',
r2d8-bot_1  |     '/usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/build/default/addon.node',
r2d8-bot_1  |     '/usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/compiled/14.17.0/linux/x64/addon.node',
r2d8-bot_1  |     '/usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/addon-build/release/install-root/addon.node',
r2d8-bot_1  |     '/usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/addon-build/debug/install-root/addon.node',
r2d8-bot_1  |     '/usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/addon-build/default/install-root/addon.node',
r2d8-bot_1  |     '/usr/src/app/node_modules/libpq/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-x64/addon.node'
r2d8-bot_1  |   ]
r2d8-bot_1  | }
r2d8_r2d8-bot_1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: What's in your Dockerfile?  The `volumes:` in the `docker-compose.yml` file hide everything in the `/usr/src/app` directory in the image; if you ran `npm install` in the Dockerfile, that includes the `node_modules` directory.  Delete the `volumes:` to use the code built into the image.

Comment: I have edited my post to include the Dockerfile. I do run a yarn install in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Then this is your issue, run it in an `entrypoint`, rather.

Comment: I changed cmd to entrypoint but still get the same error I don't think that's it.

Comment: Whats `r2d8-bot` ? i cant find it anywhere on docker

Comment: @Areg It's my Node container (the Dockerfile). You won't find it on Docker Hub because as you can see from my question I'm still in the process of getting everything created and working together successfully for the first time.